# SQL SUM with LIMIT alias returns "undefined index"

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

Could someone tell me what's wrong with this code? The page returns a:

```
Notice: Undefined index: totlvlown in /home/admin/domains/reincarnationgame.com/public_html/alliancespar.php on line 82
```

My code is:

```
$query = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT sum(level) FROM (SELECT player.level FROM player WHERE player.alliance = '.$alliance.' ORDER BY player.level DESC LIMIT '.$playersown.') AS totlvlown');
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$totallvlown = $row['totlvlown'];
```

Variables $alliance and $playersown are simple integers. Will later be replace with binded values.

I'm new to subqueries and can't seem to get this to work. I tried moving the AS part to before the FROM part but that just tells me all tables need an alias.

Comment: I've done some more research and all I can find tells me this query should work. The problem seems to lie in the alias and it not setting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution Because I think you have to start table name then `alias name` so that the level `alias`  can be recognized by the `sum function`

```
$queryalliancelvlown = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT player level sum(level)
FROM 
(
  SELECT player.level
  FROM player
  WHERE player.alliance = '.$alliance.' 
  ORDER BY player.level DESC LIMIT '.$playersown.'
) AS totlvlown');
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; error in 'sum(level) FROM (SELECT player.level FROM player WHERE player.alliance = 1 ORDER' at line 1' in /home/admin/domains/reincarnationgame.com/public_html/alliancespar.php:80 Stack trace: #0 /home/admin/domains/reincarnationgame.com/public_html/alliancespar.php(80): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/admin/domains/reincarnationgame.com/public_html/alliancespar.php on line 80